# how to automate silverlight multiple file upload?

Tags: silverlight, flash, selenium

As a client i have to upload files through a form, which was previously html form. I have permission to upload files. I automated file uploading by perl script to reduce monotonousness. But recently they replace file uploading option using silverlight 2. Like flash silverlight used object. I find no clue to expose underlying DOM of siverlight object. Thus i am not able to automate this task. Any idea, how i can automate this task?